# use Spatial filter tool running time take more

Tags: arcobjects

I want to check any 3 way junction or 4 way junction features snapping or not. I have used spatial filer it is taking more time for running could you please tell me any way to improve tool running speed.

```c#
    IWorkspaceFactory pfwf = new AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    IWorkspace pwork = pfwf.OpenFromFile(PGDBpath, 0);
    IFeatureWorkspace pfwspace = pwork as IFeatureWorkspace;
    IFeatureClass cenline = pfwspace.OpenFeatureClass("Centerlines");
    IFeatureCursor cen_cur = cenline.Search(null, false);
    IFeature cen_F = cen_cur.NextFeature();
    int cnt = 0;
    int count = cenline.FeatureCount(null);
    while (cen_F != null)
    {
        cnt++;
        label3.Text = cen_F.Class.AliasName + " " + cnt.ToString() + "/" + count.ToString();
        Application.DoEvents();
        IPolyline pline = cen_F.Shape as IPolyline;
        IPointCollection ppcol = pline as IPointCollection;
        for (int i = 0; i < ppcol.PointCount; i++)
        {
            IPoint ppoint = ppcol.get_Point(i);
            ITopologicalOperator ptopo = ppoint as ITopologicalOperator;
            IGeometry pgeo = ptopo.Buffer(0.1);                        
            ISpatialFilter pslt = new SpatialFilterClass();
            pslt.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
            pslt.Geometry = pgeo;
            IFeatureCursor pfcur = cenline.Search(pslt, false);
            IFeature cen_F_1 = pfcur.NextFeature();
            double dist = 0.0;
            bool chk = false;
            IProximityOperator prox = cen_F.Shape as IProximityOperator;
            while (cen_F_1 != null)
            {
                if (cen_F.OID != cen_F_1.OID)
                {
                    dist = prox.ReturnDistance(cen_F_1.Shape);
                    if (dist != 0.0)
                    {
                        chk = true;
                    }
                }
                cen_F_1 = pfcur.NextFeature();
            }
            if (chk == true)
            {
                wr.WriteLine(cen_F.OID + "," + cen_F.Class.AliasName + "," + dist + "," + "CenterLine Not snapped");
            }
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pfcur);
        }
        cen_F = cen_cur.NextFeature();
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cen_cur);
    wr.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Completed");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code.. that's unreadable.

Comment: "Wall of code" questions tend to get voted down and closed. You need to **edit** the question to provide a great more detail in describing the problem, including details of how the data is stored, what the actual times involved are (in milliseconds), and what steps you have taken to ensure optimal performance.

Comment: if you don't mind could you please tell me how to edit equation text and code separate.

Comment: @SATYA It's too bad you never accept anybody's answer or thank those who took the time to comment on your problem. Hornby is an arcobjects expert that went out of his way to read your code and provide some helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving these lines above the `while` statement as they need to be called only once.

```
ISpatialFilter pslt = new SpatialFilterClass(); 
pslt.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
```

Also set your cursors to be recycling there are performance advantages as discussed [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000047000000.htm).